# How to blend between textures easily using nodes?

Tags: shaders

So, I have a system that basically allows me to blend several images together over time.

However, it is a horrible system.

There are keyframes tightly packed keyframes all over the dope sheet.  Here is it:

[image]

I manually wrote a GLSL shader to do this with OGRE3D back in the day,  could I plug that into blender?  I may have lost the code...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Sure there is a simpler setup, you can exploit math nodes to do really cool stuff. What I think you want to do is to **blend between all 3 textures but using only 1 animated property**:

[image]

[image]

Here I used colors instead of textures but it is the same thing. You can also expand this setup for more than 3 inputs and still having to animate only 1 value.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think there is an easier way to do it necessarily, however you can make a custom **Group Node**.

[image: Final Node Result]

Select all the nodes you want to include (image textures and color mix nodes) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>. Then drag from the *Input* node to the vectors and the mix values:

[image: Make Node Group]

You can now edit all the values easily. Just press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to go back to normal view, or <kbd>Tab</kbd> again to edit the selected group node.

Also, once it is created, you can add it in the scene by using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *> Group > (group node name)*

[image: Add Node Group]